# Error 'useCounter is not defined' when using compostables inside Nuxt.js server API. How to solve it?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

if i use any compostables inside defineEventHandler and try to fetch data i got error that the compostable is not defined

```
export default defineEventHandler( async function(event) {
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
    const from = useDateFormat(new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1)), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    const to = useDateFormat(useNow(), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    
    const response = await $fetch(runtimeConfig.baseUrl, {
        params: {
            key: runtimeConfig.apiKey,
            ordering: 'rating',
            dates: from.value + ',' + to.value,
        }
    })

    return response
})
```

and i got

````
message: "useCounter is not defined"
statusCode: 500
statusMessage: ""
url: "/api/games/popular"
}```

index.vue 

`const { data: gamePopular, pending: popularPending } = await useFetch<PageableList<GameCardInfo>>('/api/games/popular')`

it happen with any compostables, at least vueuse compostables


how can i solve this problem?
````

Comment: Have you use/import `useCounter` in any files?